# jQuery Cycle on html elements instead of images?

Tags: jquery, cycle, element

Is it possible to use the jquery cycle plugin on elements such as a bunch of div tags instead of img tags?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it, but a quick Google query turned up [this page of examples](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/int2.html), where the very last one on the page is cycling non-image content. So I guess the answer is yes, you can.